# softlayer bandwidth pool delete

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

is there any method to delete a record for bandwidth pools??
for the api- SoftLayer_Network_Bandwidth_Version1_Allotment

Comment: please edit your question and add some formatting

Comment: @ArminŠupuk - got getObject sorted now need help for delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method to delete a bandwidth pool is “requestVdrCancellation” of the service “SoftLayer_Network_Bandwidth_Version1_Allotment”.

You can use this rest api:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Bandwidth_Version1_Allotment/[bandwidthPoolId]/requestVdrCancellation
```